# MonoTouch Dialog--Not enough space between string and entry

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

How can I widen the space that the strings take up.  The text for the entry text is overlapping with the text for the string that corresponds to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to build a custom Element that can render precisely the way that you want.   The built-in elements do not offer a lot of configuration options.